# Docker file with apt package

Tags: linux, apt, docker, apk-tools

I have below two commands using apk

```
apk add --no-cache curl && \
    curl -sSLO https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local/releases/download/v${VERSION}/sam_${VERSION}_linux_386.tar.gz && \
    tar -C /usr/local/bin -zxvf /sam_${VERSION}_linux_386.tar.gz && \
    apk del curl && \
    rm -f /sam_${VERSION}_linux_386.tar.gz

# awscli for "sam package" and "sam deploy"
apk add --no-cache py-pip && pip install awscli
```

---

I need to run these two commands using `apt`

---

What are the corresponding commands using `apt-get`?

Comment: From [the openjdk Docker page](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk): "Starting with openjdk:12 the default image as well as the -oracle and -oraclelinux7 variants are based on the official Oracle Linux 7 image".  If you want to use `apt`, consider: "Some of these tags may have names like stretch in them. These are the suite code names for releases of Debian and indicate which release the image is based on."

Answer (score 5):

The `apt-get` equivalents for the `apk` commands used in your snippet are as follows:

- `apk add --no-cache curl`: `apt-get install -o APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages=false curl`
- `apk del curl`: `apt-get purge curl`
- `apk add --no-cache py-pip`: `apt-get install -o APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages=false python-pip`

(The last command assumes you’re after `pip` for Python 2; use `python3-pip` for Python 3.)